# Rational systole of a manifold

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, homology

I also posted this question on MSE, but since it may be a delicate question, I decided to post it here.

Given a Riemannian manifold $(M^n,g)$ and an integer $1 \leq k \leq n-1$, the $k$-systole of $M$ is given by

$$\operatorname{sys}_k(M,g) = \inf \{ \mathcal{H}^k(\Sigma) : \Sigma^k \in \mathcal{S} \text{ and } [\Sigma] \neq 0 \in H_k(M; \mathbb{Z}) \},$$

where $\mathcal{S}$ denotes the set of all closed $k$-dimensional submanifolds of $M$ and $\mathcal{H}^k$ denotes the $k$-Hausdorff measure.

Is it possible to make sense of a "rational $k$-systole" by changing the homology coefficients to be $\mathbb{Q}$? I worry because if $\Sigma \in \mathcal{S}$, then $H_k(\Sigma; \mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Q}$ is not a finitely generated abelian group, and we cannot pushforward a "fundamental class" by the inclusion $i : \Sigma \to M$ to impose $[\Sigma] \neq 0 \in H_k(M; \mathbb{Q})$.

On the other hand, Gromov defines the $1$-systole of a manifold with coefficients in **any** abelian group [here](https://www.ihes.fr/%7Egromov/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/195.pdf), on page 9.

Comment: The MSE crosspost is found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4059493/rational-systole-of-a-manifold) and has now been answered.